# PHP JPEG Functions Not Working

Tags: php, gd, jpeg

Any PHP functions that deal with JPEGs don't seem to be working on my server.

This code:

```
<?php
$im = imagecreatetruecolor(120, 20);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'A Simple Text String', $text_color);
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

creates an empty file.

Using a GIF or PNG function will create an image containing the text "A Simple Text String" as expected.

This:

```
$im = imagecreatefromjpeg("test.jpg");
```

returns

```
Warning: imagecreatefromjpeg() [function.imagecreatefromjpeg]: 'test.jpg' is not a valid JPEG file in /path/to/test.php on line 2
```

A phpinfo() shows:

```
gd
GD Support  enabled
GD Version  2.0 or higher
FreeType Support    enabled
FreeType Linkage    with freetype
FreeType Version    2.3.9
T1Lib Support   enabled
GIF Read Support    enabled
GIF Create Support  enabled
JPG Support     enabled
PNG Support     enabled
WBMP Support    enabled
```

And the webserver can read any relevant files.

GIF and PNG functions work fine, and as expected.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

Found this in my Apache error log file:

```
gd-jpeg: JPEG library reports unrecoverable error: Wrong JPEG library version: library is 80, caller expects 62
```

Comment: If you are sure `test.jpg` is a valid JPG file (Note GD can't deal with CMYK JPGs - make sure it's RGB! Also try using a different file), then this seems to be a server configuration issue better asked on serverfault.com.

Comment: Have tried with several different files with the same result

Answer (score 6):

Your error log clearly shows that your PHP is compiled against/requires `libjpeg` version 62, while the library on your server is version 80.

Either install the correct version of `libjpeg`, or recompile `gd`/`php`.

Comment: apt-get tells me that
    "libjpeg62-dev is already the newest version"

Comment: libjpeg62 is the library, libjpeg62-dev are just headers. Also, are you using the standard php/gd packages?

Comment: Yes, standard as installed by "apt get install"

Answer (score 0):

It appears that the file `test.jpg` doesn't exist, or isn't the correct filetype headers (eg, if someone renames a test.png as test.jpg it will still have the .png headers). Try creating a new test.jpg file using an image editing program and see if it works.

Comment: Have tried this, and still not working. Just to confirm that it did exist and I'd got the path right, I tried to open one that was deliberately wrong, and it gave me a different error (Can't open file, or similar)

Answer (score 0):

An answer that worked for me was to work around the image altogether and trearit as a string.

Ill try to do it the standard way, but if it doesnt work, try it as a string

```
      $src = imagecreatefromjpeg($file);
      if (!$src) {
      $src = imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($file));
      }
```

There are apparently some issue wilth older versions or combos of GD an PHP.

In my case I had an image using a newer version/compression of jpeg 7 I think.