# php Image processing (convert jpeg to png or gif or wbmp)

Tags: php, image-processing

The situation is like this :
A server returns me a picture which is in jpeg format. Now I have to do some processing on the image (like writing caption on it,..). Since **my server does not support jpeg**, I want to convert it to a format that my server supports(png,gif and wbmp). How can I convert the image returned by the server into png/gif/wbmp format without using `imagecreatefromjpeg` ?

Comment: In what way does your server not support jpeg? are you saying that the `imagecreatefromjpeg()` function is not available in your PHP?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php

Comment: @SDC the server which returns the image is not my server where I host my php script.And my server does not support `imagecreatefromjpeg()`

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477896/php-jpeg-functions-not-working

Answer (score 0):

Try  Imagine http://imagine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html

Comment: I am not admin of my server. Do i need to install Imagine to use it?

Comment: hm, Imagine uses some of the GD libraries. Something like a wrapper. Its all PHP files, you need to upload to server. Have a look into the example pointed in it.

Answer (score 0):

In what way does your server not support jpeg? are you saying that the `imagecreatefromjpeg()` function is not available in your PHP?

Assuming this is the case, then it doesn't mean that your server "doesn't support jpeg"; what it means is that your copy of PHP doesn't have the GD library installed. This will affect all PHP's graphic processing functions, not just JPEG ones.

If you have the ability to install PHP extensions, or to ask your server admin to install them, then installing the GD library will be by far the easiest solution to this problem.

If you don't have that ability, you will still need to install *something* onto your server in order to read and process an image (of any type, not just jpeg).

A common tool for this is [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/). This is a stand-alone tool, so you can install it and call it from the command line (ie using PHP's `exec` command, etc). There is also a [PHP extension to control it](http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php), but obviously this will have the same issue as the GD library if it isn't already installed.

But ultimately, whatever you do, it will involve installing something on your server.

Comment: http://www.picamatic.com/show/2012/07/10/03/41/8511664_627x335.PNG this image is the part of my phpinfo(). I does have gd installed but jpeg is not supported.

Comment: are you saying that your ISP has installed PHP with GD installed but the JPEG part of GD disabled?? Why would they do that? Have you asked them? It sounds a bit weird.

Comment: This might be related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477896/php-jpeg-functions-not-working (sounds like a similar problem; the issue there was a configuration error on the server)

Comment: It would be worth checking if your server already has imagemagick installed; it's not a given, but it's common enough that they might have it. If they do, it's a quick solution to the problem, without having to do any installing.

Comment: No they have not installed the imagemagick.I confirmed. Please help! What other options do I have other than installing any thing?

Comment: if all else fails, it *should* be possible to install imageMagick into your own home directory; ie not a proper "install", so you won't need admin permissions for it. That won't include the PHP extension, so you'd have to call it using `exec`. It would be a bit of a painful solution, but it should be enough to allow you to do what you need to. But frankly, you should be hassling your server provider as to why you can't read JPEGs. It's fairly basic functionality, so if they've broken it then they should fix it.