# Heroku not Supporting jpg in GD

Tags: php, git, facebook-graph-api, heroku, git-bash

i recently came to know that jpgs wont work in heroku's gd. i am developing facebook application that uses profile pics which are in jpg format.how do i process these jpg images without gd.i am using windows git bash utility.
i want an answer to any one of these..

1)how do I convert A jpg Image to Png without using php gd ?(so i can process this png image using php gd).

2)how do i set up an environment to process jpg images with php gd or any other in heroku using git?.(i may need detailed step by step tuturial as i Have only basic knowledge about git bash .please mention where to download resources)

3)in graph api is there anything that changes the extension of returning image
like- graph.facebook.com/user/picture?ext=png something like that?

Thanks for your Support

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3477896/php-jpeg-functions-not-working

Comment: that doesnt solve my problem //it does not involve heroku.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9573916/how-can-i-add-jpeg-support-to-heroku-php-buildpack